# Find which graphics card is being used Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: graphics-card

I used the following command:

```
lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Dell Skylake Integrated Graphics
    Kernel driver in use: i915_bpo
--
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330] (rev ff)
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83)
```

and it shows the result above. Do I have 2 graphics card ? Intel and Radeon ?

I typed this to get the currently used one:

```
glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2) 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 11.2.0
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 11.2.0
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Does it mean that I am using Intel instead of Radeon ? Which is better ? Can I switch to another card ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically no, you have only 1 graphics **card**. However you do have 2 GPUs (that is what matters)

One is an integrated Intel, part of your CPU chip: an [HD520](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HD_and_Iris_Graphics)

The second one is a discreet (meaning it is on its onn card): an AMD Radeon card. Looks like a 8670M or 8690M.

For easy tasks the system will use the integrated GPU (as it requires less power to run), and for fancy stuff it will switch to the AMD, as it should be noticeable more powerful.

Comment: Is Radeon 8670M decent GPU ? I run tekken 3 on PCSX(PS 1) emulator on ubuntu and it lags on medium resolution as well. I run it at 640*480 for smoother experience. Even 800*600 lags.

Comment: 1) If you find that your question has been answered, please click the accept answer button.

Comment: 2) What is "decent" depends on what your purpose is. What rendering capabilities you need, OS compatibility, budget, power use, drivers, etc. If you need more info about an 8670M just google some review like [this one](https://www.notebookcheck.net/AMD-Radeon-HD-8670M.87211.0.html). If you have more question regarding the 8670M, please open a new clearly defined question.